# Web Project Structure - Can I nest server file in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

I'm fairly new to web development, but I've take a couple hands-on introductory courses where the basic structure of a website is you have an HTML file (or several ejs template files), a CSS file, and then you have something called a "server" file which is a JavaScript file, typically called `app.js`

I know that if I wanted to, I could include all my CSS inside the HTML file in `<style>` tags. My question is, should I have the need to do so, would it be possible for me to include the server code in `<script>` tags within a single HTML file?

Debating on whether or not I should put forth the effort to attempt to do so, but if it's generally problematic (note: I don't car about "best practice") for some reason such as it prevents you from working with certain packages/modules like EJS or Node.js then I will likely conclude that it doesn't make sense to try. As a novice web developer, I fear I am not aware of certain restrictions that I would likely run into if any (besides lack of module support).

Comment: @devlincarnate — See https://expressjs.com/ for the most common use of server-side JS.

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible for me to include the server code in `<script>` tags within a single HTML file?

No.

Web browsers, which execute the scripts in webpages, do not provide JavaScript programs with the APIs required to run a server.

If you want to write a web server in JavaScript then you'll need to run it using a tool like Node.js and not a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot put ***server-side code*** in HTML or in JS files that are sent to the client. Server-side code is code that is run on a server that you host, while client-side code is code that is run on the computer of the person who is visiting your webpage.

You can put ***client-side code*** in [HTML `<script>` tags.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), and you can also include client-side code in separate JS files. The drawbacks are immense though, as:

1. Code highlighters won't be able to highlight your code and point out things like syntax errors as easily.
2. You won't be able to use tools like Babel and TypeScript, which input and output JS files.
3. You can't use NPM modules without a bundler like Webpack, which itself will output JS files.

Overall, there isn't really a good reason to use the `<script>` tag. It takes 2 extra seconds to just create another file for your JS, and it's more organized, more modularized and easier to use with external tools.